# How to turn image links/url into an image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a set of image links and I want to turn them into an image using JavaScript and the links are dynamic which are coming from an API. So how can I turn those links into an image. I want all the images to show for example: I have 7 image URLs so I want all the 7 URLs to get turned into an image and not only 1

The links are in a div like:

```
<div class="avatar"></div>
```

And the data is coming by an API using JS:

```
const getimage = () => {
    axios
        .get(
            "https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/contributors"
        )
        .then((response) => {
            const users = response.data;
            console.log(users)
            const avatar = document.querySelector(".avatar")
            avatar.innerHTML=users.map((u) => u.avatar_url).join("<br />");
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
};
getimage();
```

How can I do that

Comment: Show an example of what the links you've got and an attempt to make this work. We'll help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make a loop for all links and create image tag and then set `src` attribute and finally append to body.

Try this one:

```js
var array = ["link1", "link2"];
array.forEach((t) => {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = t;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
})
```

**Update based on question**

```js
     var users = ["link1", "link2"];
     const avatar = document.querySelector(".avatar")
     users.map((u) => {
         var img = document.createElement("img");
         img.src = u.avatar_url;
         avatar.appendChild(img);
         avatar.innerHTML += `<br/>`;
     })
```

```html
  <div class="avatar">

    </div>
```